# How to send raw request using node-fetch?

Tags: node.js, http, webserver, node-fetch

`node-fetch` can be found here: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch

I want to send a plain request such as:

```
GET /search?q=test HTTP/2
Host: www.bing.com
User-Agent: <someAgentName>
Accept: */*
```

I have no idea how to do that, or if it possible at all. If not, what can you recommend me to use?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you update your question with code examples?

Comment: I don't have any code examples because Idk what to try at all

Comment: It isn't not clear what the problem is. Are you trying to make a request without some default headers? Are you trying to explicitly make an HTTP 2 request?

Comment: "I don't have any code examples because Idk what to try at all" — Starting with the documentation for the library you want to use is generally a good point. See also [this meta post about research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: I want to explictly make the request myself, not use stuff similar to `fetch(url)`

Comment: @Quentin, I already studied the documentation and found nothing

Comment: @uIM7AI9S — Either you want to use fetch or you want to not use fetch. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: I said in the question I want to use `node-fetch`, but IF is not possible, then something else...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217827/discussion-between-quentin-and-uim7ai9s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was quite unsatisfied with the help gave by this community... The answer is:

`node-fetch` (and other similar libraries such as `request`) is not supposed to handle raw text. It will be built internally using the options user told (such as url, headers). If you want to send the raw text, you need to look into how these libraries works under the hood

Taking HTTP as example, it is just a TCP socket, and the information exchanged is exactly the raw text block I posted in the question. So the solution is to make a TCP socket and that's it. You send the raw text through the socket